# filter an object JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to filter out an object, but does not work ....

This is the code:

```
let obj = Object.assign({},[{
        "_id": 1,
        "fecha": "2016-09-28T20:49:00.000Z"
    }, {
        "_id": 2,
        "fecha": "2016-09-26T20:48:00.000Z"
    }, {
        "_id": 3,
        "fecha": "2016-09-26T21:04:00.000Z"
    }, {
        "_id": 4,
        "fecha": "2016-09-23T21:02:00.000Z"
    }, {
        "_id": 14,
        "fecha": "2016-09-24T21:02:00.000Z"
    }, {
        "_id": 15,
        "fecha": "2016-09-24T21:01:00.000Z"
    }, {
        "_id": 17,
        "fecha": "2016-09-23T19:04:00.000Z"
    }, {
        "_id": 18,
        "fecha": "2016-09-23T19:24:00.000Z"
    }, {
        "_id": 23,
        "fecha": "2016-09-23T21:04:00.000Z"
    }]
);
console.log(obj);

let result = obj.filter(item => item._id == 1)[0];
console.log(result);
```

the result is:

Object {0: Object, 1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object, 5: Object, 6: Object, 7: Object, 8: Object}
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: obj.find is not a function(…)

note: obj is not defined in the function, it comes from another system, but I write to show your defición

Comment: Filter is an array method. If you do `let obj = [{` then no errors

Comment: You cannot do a filter over `Object`.

Comment: `Object.assign({}, [])` is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

I can't use methods of `Array` on `Object`. Assume you receipt `obj` variable as an Object. You should convert it to an array. Try this:

```
Object.keys(obj).map((i) => obj[i]).filter(e => e._id === 1)
```

Comment: check it as the answer to close your question please. Thank you ! =)